# Why `getline` could acquire the output of the pipe as soon as possible, whereas `setvbuf` & `fread` does not work

Tags: c, linux, pipe, getline, fread

I hope to see the output of the command executed by `popen` as soon as possible.So I change the buffering type of the file stream returned by `popen` to line buffered. As per the [document](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf), **`setvbuf` seems work for this goal**. I did a simple test on `Ubuntu16.4`, **it does not make any difference indeed**.

Here is the code snippet which I used to do the said test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
    FILE* file = popen("bash -c \"for i in 1 2 3 4 5;do echo -e -n 'thanks a lot\n'; sleep 1; done\" ", "r");
    


    if(NULL != file)
    {
        int size;
        printf("setvbuf returns %d\n", setvbuf(file, NULL, _IOLBF, 0)); 
        while((size = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, file))>0)
        {
            printf("size=%d\n", size);
            memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of the code snippet which runs on `Ubuntu16.04`:

```
setvbuf returns 0
//about five seconds later
size=65
```

As per the [document](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf), which says that:

> The function setvbuf() returns 0 on success.

As per the output above, `setvbuf(file, NULL, _IOLBF, 0)`  has successfully set the buffing type of `file` returned by `popen` to line buffered.But the output of the aforementioned code snippet indicates it still uses the default block buffered.

But when I tried `getline`, it could achieve the goal, which is really out of my expectation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* file = popen("bash -c \"for i in 1 2 3 4 5;do echo -e -n 'thanks a lot\n'; sleep 1; done\" ", "r");
 
    char* line=NULL;
    size_t len;
    if(NULL != file)
    {
//      std::cout << setvbuf(file, NULL, _IOLBF, 0) << std::endl; //setvbuf has not been called
        while(getline(&line, &len, file)>0)
        {
            printf("strlen(line)=%lu\n", strlen(line));
            free(line);
            line = NULL;
        }
    }
    
    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
//one second later
strlen(line)=13
//one second later
strlen(line)=13
//one second later
strlen(line)=13
//one second later
strlen(line)=13
//one second later
strlen(line)=13
```

I am really conscious about why `getline` could acquire the output of the pipe as soon as possible, whereas `setvbuf` & `fread` does not work.

Comment: Did you try reading one character at a time (with `fgetc`)? Even though the input is not buffered, the call to `fread` will still block while it waits for up to 1024 characters and most likely only unblocks as a result of the pipe being closed.

Comment: @paddy "the call to fread will still block while it waits for up to 1024 characters". You mean no matter which type of buffering is used by the file descriptor, `fread` always  waits for up to 1024 characters?

Comment: Well, you _told_ it to read 1024 characters. The difference with no buffering is that if 1024 characters arrive but there is no newline in the last position then it will return those immediately. Conversely, with buffering enabled, the pipe might receive more than 1024 characters but they are not seen by `fread` until either a newline or flush happens, or the buffer becomes full, or EOF / error is encountered.

Comment: @paddy Even with no buffering, `fread` still ***has to wait for*** 1024 characters have been successfully received by the pipe. It's really out of my expectation.

Comment: It shouldn't be out of your expectation. Essentially what you're doing here is _double-buffering_. You are reading a fixed number of bytes into a buffer, but the underlying I/O buffering mechanism does its own thing regarding when those bytes are actually returned. It does not matter _what_ bytes are put into your buffer. `fread` should not return immediately just because it encountered a newline. You asked for 1024 and that's what you should get, unless no more bytes are available in the file. Note that I/O being blocked is completely different from I/O being terminated.

Comment: @paddy Could you please explain more about the differences between `fread` with block buffering and `fread` with no buffering? In both cases, `fread`  has to wait for 1024 characters have been successfully received by the pipe despite EOF or a specific error occurs.

Comment: I keep trying to explain in different ways. Let's simplify the problem. Imagine you ask `fread` to read only 2 bytes. Now, the user is going to type `hi` and then press Enter. If there is line buffering, `fread` will not return until _after_ the user presses Enter because actually the entire input is held in an internal buffer and `fread` hasn't read _anything_ until the input is delivered. If there is no buffering, then `fread` will return before the user presses Enter. If instead the user only types `h` and then does nothing for 1 second, `fread` will not magically return this 1 byte.

Comment: @paddy I see. Thank you so much. This example is so good!

Answer (score 1):

`getline` stops reading once it gets to a newline. `fread` keeps reading until it reads as much data as you specified (in your case, 1024 bytes) or it encounters EOF or an error. This has nothing to do with buffering. You might want to look at `read` to see if it's closer to what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I can't fully understand ***This has nothing to do with buffering***. Could you please explain that in more detail?  Do you mean `setvbuf` does not influence `fread` & `getline`?

Comment: @John No, that's not what I meant. I meant that the problem you're experiencing has nothing to do with the fact that they're buffered.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeremy Friesner'answer:

In my experience, the call to setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0) needs to be executed inside the child process in order to get the behavior you want. (Of course that's much easier to achive if the child process's executable is one you control rather than /bin/bash). popen() in the parent process can't give you data that the child process hasn't supplied to it yet.